# OBJ-C - Getting a class name from a class hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Let's say I have the following headers:

```
@interface SuperClass  : NSObject

@interface SubClass : SuperClass
```

I'm alloc'ing an instance of the class by doing:

```
 SubClass *sc = [[SubClass alloc] init];
```

In my SuperClass.m:

```
- (id) init
{
 self = [super init];
 if (self != nil)
 {
   NSString *cString = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
 }
 return self;
}
```

Simple, right? My question is: how can I get cString to return the SuperClass class, rather than the SubClass class?
Since the SubClass is alloc'd/init'd, is this not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: There are all sorts of ways to accomplish this, with the simplest being Carl's suggestion that if you always want the same string, just use a static string. If there is some deeper problem you want to solve here, it might be good to let us in on it so we can offer better suggestions for how to go about it.

Comment: Agree with Chuck.  I can't think of a reason ever to need to know the name of the supeclass.  Maybe there's a better way todo what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want the same string to come out, why not just:

```
NSString *classString = @"SuperClass";
```

Comment: I may end up resorting to this, but SubClass may be further subclassed (ie. SubSubClass). If possible I would rather not have each subclass have to hard-code this if I can use `[self class]` for each super class.

Answer (score 6):

If you always want to get the super class,

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        NSString *cString = NSStringFromClass([self superclass]);
    }
    return self;
}
```

If you `alloc`+`init` a SubClass, then `cString` will contain “SuperClass”, but, if you `alloc`+`init` a SuperClass, then `cString` will contain “NSObject”.